# How to convert date string to Date data type

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I have a

`String dateString = "Fri Feb 14 00:00:00 IST 2014";`

I need output in Date datatype like `2014-02-14`.

Here is the code which is throwing `Parse exception`.

Need help in this.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

    String dateString = "Fri Feb 14 00:00:00 IST 2014";

        Date convertedDate = null;
        try {
            convertedDate = df.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(convertedDate);

}
```

Comment: Obviously, `Fri Feb 14 00:00:00 IST 2014` does not match the `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` format... See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

*Base point is - **Input string should match with date pattern***

Raised parse exception as becasue wrong pattern, use this date pattern - `EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy`

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `dateString` to matching `Date` format and then you can format that `Date` what ever the format you want.

Try this

```
  DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
  DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
  String dateString = "Fri Feb 14 00:00:00 IST 2014";
  Date date=df2.parse(dateString); // convert stringDate to matching Date format
  System.out.println(df1.format(date));
```

Out put:

```
  2014-02-14 12:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");

    String dateString = "Fri Feb 14 00:00:00 IST 2014";

    Date convertedDate = null;
    try {
        convertedDate = df.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(convertedDate);
}
```

Comment: This gives the same output... I need something like 2014-02-14

Comment: I don't think so, i have checked it, and it working fine. i think you have missed something.